# How to get rid of strange white line under QTabBar while customzing Tabified QDockWidgets thru stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

here's is the style sheet I used for a modified version Qt Mainwindow example:

```
QWidget { background: #757575 }
QTabWidget { padding: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: #757575; }
QTabWidget::pane { border: 0px solid #C2C7CB;  top: -3px; background: #757575; }
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    subcontrol-position: top left;

    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    }

QTabBar { background-color : #757575; }
QTabBar::close-button {
   subcontrol-position: right;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    color: white;
   background: #757575;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   min-width: 8ex;
   padding: 10px;
   min-width: 100px;
}

QTabBar::tab::selected{ border-bottom: 0px solid #757575; background-color: darkgrey; }
```

The pic below shows the output of the above stylesheet on QDockWidget example

Here's a link for the Project
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6cx8jGbgXo7Z0xucXBaSEljMGc

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QTabBar strange line doesn't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551058/qtabbar-strange-line-doesnt-disappear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTabBar::setDrawBase(false);` this function can solve the problem.hope this may help you.

Comment: thanks, basically it solved the issue, but it was hard to search for that QTabBar* within QMainWindow class, I had to use

    QList<QTabBar*> tabBars = findChildren<QTabBar*>("", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);

to find the QTabBar object in order set setDrawBase to false.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this issue really exist. In `QMainWindow` class, we cannot get the `QTabBar` pointer. This also confuse me, for example, I want custom the tabbar in `QMainWindow` to make the tab can be drag in my way. So far, I do not resolve this problem. I maybe need a interface like `QMainWindow::setTabbar(QTabbar *);`

Comment: The only things that helped me is that I've installed an eventfilter on the QMainWindow object, then I filtered the paintEvent, after that I could call      QList<QTabBar*> tabBars = findChildren<QTabBar*>("", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);

Answer (score 0):

This is a default border that was not redefined. Although I cannot reproduce the problem with your style sheets (things show up correctly to me), the solution is to redefine the `border` property, probably from the `QToolBar`

```
QToolBar {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #757575;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it's didn't solve the problem that white line still there. The problem is reproduce-able under MacOS and Linux Ubuntu with Qt 5.7.1 and even Qt 5.8.0. I also tried 
    * {
        border: 0;
        background-color: #757575;
    }
but it didn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I tested only on Windows yet, but the border disappeared when I did set `QToolBar { border: 0 }`. The behavior may be different on Mac also due to the `setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);` line. If you confirm it has no impact, I'll give it a shot on a linux disto.

Comment: Again, it has no impact at all. I'll attach the project I am working on, since it might not show up in normal QTabWidget.

Comment: Tried multiple combinations, but had luck unfortunately. Several post actually relate the problem, and that would be worth digging in Qt code to see if it's doable at all

Comment: By the way the issue is reproduceable with windows 10, I've just tried it, it's there. Have used the Code I've provided?

Comment: I didn't tried your code on winows 10, but on a Ubuntu it showed exactly the same. Had a small idea to test, maybe setting the palette of the widget may help to "hide" it

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it didn't help. Event without the stylesheet just with palettes (i.e. setPalette), still this white line persists.